# codeigniter session with ajax input is not working

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

**view**

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">

        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"  id="login">Sign In</button>
```

here i pass the values to the controller using ajax

```
<script>
  $(function()
  {
    $('#login').click(function()
    {
      var username=$("#username").val();
      var password=$("#password").val();
      $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>home/check_login",
      type:"POST",
      async:false,
      data:{username:username,password:password},
      success:function(data)
       {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var count = Object.keys(obj).length;
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(count);
           if(obj.length==1)
           {
          window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url();?>home/show_dashboard";
           }
           else if(obj.length==0)
           {    
             $('#modal_warning').modal('show');
           } 
        }
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

**and my controller is**

```
public function check_login()
    {
        $username= $this->input->post('username');
        $password= $this->input->post('password');

        $newdata = array(
               'username'  => $username,


           );


        $this->session->set_userdata('ci_session',$newdata);

        $details=$this->user_model->check_username($username,$password);
        echo json_encode($details);
    }
```

**when click log out button**

```
public function log_out()
    {   
        if($this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session'))
        {
        $this->load->view('login');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "nooo";
            exit;
        }
    }
```

when i click the logout button it gives me "noo" which i placed in else part.
When i try to print the session data, it prints nothing. How can I set session which data is passing by ajax.

I also loaded session library

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `$this->set_userdata('ci_session',$newdata);` without the session. Do it like so to set session variables. `$this->session->set_userdata('ci_session',$newdata);`

Also make sure the session driver is loaded. To access the session variable you can do `print_r($this->session->ci_session)`

Further:

Unset userdata doesn't actually return anything:

```
/**
 * Unset userdata
 *
 * Legacy CI_Session compatibility method
 *
 * @param   mixed   $key    Session data key(s)
 * @return  void
 */
public function unset_userdata($key)
{
    if (is_array($key))
    {
        foreach ($key as $k)
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$k]);
        }

        return;
    }

    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

hence its always evaluating to false. The function itself is just an alias for `unset($_SESSION[$key])` you can view the function in the session core file. There is no need for the conditional statement; just `$this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session'); redirect(...);` is sufficient.

Comment: thank you for your reply,but its not working,its still goes to the else part

Comment: public function log_out()
 {   print_r($this->session->ci_session);
   exit;
  $this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session');
  if($this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session'))
  {
  redirect('home/index');
  }
  else
  {
   print_r($this->session->ci_session);
   exit;
  }
 }this gives me the session data successfully,but I cant unset the session data

Comment: public function log_out()
 { 
       $this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session');
       print_r( $this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session'));
       exit;} when i print this there is nothing prints, so I thing the session is unset successfully. but when I click the browser back-arrow it takes me to the previous page

Comment: why wouldn't it? that's what the back button does... refresh the page after you clicked the button and see if you are still logged in. if you are then I assume logic elsewhere is faulty; people usually have something like `if (!isset($this->session->user_id)) { redirect('/login'); }` to protect auth controllers (I assume you do too, otherwise you really should do some research)